# how to view an extremely large file on a sever: Freebase

Tags: view, bigdata, data-dump

I'm trying to look at the [Freebase data dump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) which is stored on a server that I access through ssh. The trouble is I don't know how I can view it in a way that doesn't take forever, make things freeze or crash, I had been trying to view it with `nano` and it evokes the precisely the behaviour just described.

The operating system is *Darwin*.

How can I examine this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could use command `more` or `less` to scroll over the file. If you know which lines in the file you are interested in, like from line 3000 to 3999, you could show them with `sed -n '3000,3999p' your_file_name`.

Comment: but i don't really know anything about the file, or how its structured

Comment: you could use `more file_name` or `less file_name` to scroll over the beginning part of the file to see how it's like, or `tail -n #lines file_name` to show the bottom part, or combine `tail` or `head` with `more` like `tail -n #lines file_name | more`. Once you know what you are interested in, you could use `grep` to search for that. Or perhaps you could download it for the first time analysis, and use desktop softwares like 'Sublime text' to open and view it in a more convenient way. 'Sublime text' could be able to open a file smaller than the available memory of the OS.